# Cordova Crosswalk - error after ionic and Android SDK update

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I just updated Android SDK and the Ionic dependencies in my app.

After the running command:

```
cordova build android
cordova run android
```

I get this error message:

> Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 3.7.1, failed version requirement: >=4.0.0-dev

I tried to change target SDK value in AndroidManifest and config back into SDK v. 19, but without luck.

Comment: Really nobody knows what can cause this issue?

Comment: may have to roll back from crosswalk canary

Comment: I tried add new crosswalk using : ionic browser add crosswalk and then cordova cordova platform add android, but after cordova run i always get same error message.